# teller and customer counter

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I am trying  to write a program in verilog about bank operations, so just a simple question, I have customer queue and teller counter, how can I write a formula to teller counter.

Below i tried to write something but if you have any idea if its wrong or true i would like to hear. In addition I need to implement if `teller counter =customer counter` then teller counter needs to be increase. Thank you so much for your helps!

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin        
  case (current_state)
    IDLE:       
      teller_count <= cust_count;
    teller: 
      teller_count <= teller_count+1;
    default:
      teller_count <= teller_count;
  endcase
end
```

Comment: Where have you written the `rst` logic? This seems like an FSM, where is implementation of `... if teller counter =customer counter then teller counter needs to be increase....` logic? Can you show some more code?

Comment: I am guessing you also have `current_state <= next_state` and some additional state logic some where. Without the reset logic your not going to be able to simulate it. May be post link to example on [EDA playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can make your life easier by writing two separate fsms, one for handling each queue. or at least two always blocks, one for each.

customer side would look like

```
    if (new_customer & !free_teller)
          customer <= customer + 1
    ...
    if (free_teller)
          customer <= customer - 1
```

teller side would look like

```
    at reset tellers = MAX_TELLER
    ...
    if (tellers == MAX_TELLER)
        free_teller = 0;
    else
        free_teller = 1;
```

got the idea?